# TinyMCE angle brackets

Tags: php, tags, tinymce

I am new to using TinyMCE but am frustrated with its behavior of angle brackets. It appears to be interpreting input such as `<foo>` or `<foo>Foo</foo>` as tags despite the page source showing that both cases are converted to `&lt;foo&gt;` and `&lt;foo&gt;Foo&lt;/foo&gt;` respectively

I reduced my code for SO, it is below:

```
<?php
    // Simplified for SO, no file writing / reading
    $content = isset($_POST["forSo"]) ? $_POST["forSo"] : "";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>For Stack Overflow</title>
    <script src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({ selector : "#forSo" });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // Behaves as expected, TinyMCE correctly automatically converts HTML Entities
    echo $content . "\n";
?>
    <form action="/forSo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea id="forSo" name="forSo">
<?php
    // Page source shows that this has HTML Entities, still loses information
    echo $content . "\n";
?>
        </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I input say `<foo>` then the resulting page source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>For Stack Overflow</title>
    <script src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({ selector : "#forSo" });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;&lt;foo&gt;</p>
    <form action="/forSo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea id="forSo" name="forSo">
<p>&nbsp;&lt;foo&gt;</p>
        </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However TinyMCE seems to have thrown away the textarea's content resulting in this (hitting submit again causes all of `$content` to be an empty string):

[image: TinyMCE making me angry]

Comment: you need to be in source view if you want to write code in tinyMCE,

Comment: @Dagon, I don't understand what you mean. To clarify,  `<foo>` was just an example I came across by chance. Some text someone wants for a page contained text like `example-<day>.txt` where they wanted `<day>` to be understood as a variable. The `<day>` part of that text vanishes just like `<foo>`

Comment: its a WYSIWIG editor on a web page, you cant give it raw html and expect it to know when you want that unescaped

Comment: Well, then what is the solution to my question?

Comment: switch to source mode to edit

Comment: This is going to be for people who do not understand HTML, there must be some way to clean `$content` in PHP so that it is sent to TinyMCE correctly

Comment: is `<day>` a placeholder\variable you replace at a later date ?

Comment: No, it is a part of some text a non-coder wants to be shown literally both on the page and in the TinyMCE editor. **Edit**: To clarify, when they write `example-<day>.txt` they expect exactly that to appear, no replacement

Comment: then there is no problem. a browser sees `<` and `&lt;` as the same thing

Comment: Take a look at the screen shot (which represents the page source I posted). The string `<foo>` appears outside the textarea because TinyMCE converted it to `&lt;foo&gt;` which is what I wanted. Although `&lt;foo&gt;` is also inside the textarea (I can see it in the page source) TinyMCE does not show it at all and clicking submit a second time will cause `$content` to be an empty string

Comment: its empty becuse `<foo>` is invalid html

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF FSM, I KNOW IT IS INVALID HTML! I am looking for a solution that preserves the text

Comment: then why are you using an editor designed to write HTML ?????

Comment: I am using TinyMCE because the end users do not know how to write HTML but they understand a text editor that generates HTML. TinyMCE correctly generates HTML and also correctly escapes HTML Entities. What I have found is that the escaped version of `<foo>` - which is `&lt;foo&gt;` - is still interpreted by TinyMCE as a HTML tag which is incorrect. All I am looking for is what to send to TinyMCE - the second time I `echo $content` in the code I posted - so that it preserves whatever they write even if it begins with `&lt;` and ends with `&gt` after TinyMCE has converted on the first submit

Comment: so TinyMCE should only escape(convert) valid HTML ?

Comment: I don't even want it to convert valid HTML, everything should be taken literally. Whatever they type should appear as they type it. None of them will ever write `<a ... >Something</a>` when they want a link, they will use the built in menu options for it. There is surely some way to do this

Comment: `tinymce.init({
        ...
        entity_encoding : "raw"
});` ?

Comment: Same result. I think I found a solution, making an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the second `<?php echo $content . "\n"; ?>` inside the textarea with `<?php echo str_replace("&", "&amp;", $content) . "\n"; ?>` accomplishes the task

This does prevent writing valid HTML tags but text that is meant to be taken literally such as `<foo>` is preserved inside the TinyMCE editor as `&amp;lt;foo&amp;gt;` as opposed to `&lt;foo&gt;` which TinyMCE interprets as a HTML tag